# How to use an empty string in Regex Literal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought I'd space out after every letter in a string, for example `foo` becomes `f o o`

What I'm thinking is `'foo'.replace(//g, ' ');` **(** the **g** flag to replace every instance, otherwise I wouldn't want regex, would I :) **).**

I only have one slight problem... in JavaScript, `//` is a comment, so it does not work.

How can I achieve this *typing* a regex literal (with slashes), or is it not possible and I would have to create (by *typing*) a Regex object?

Comment: [`/(?:)/g`](http://jsconsole.com/?new%20RegExp%28%27%27%2C%20%27g%27%29.toString%28%29), going by `new RegExp('', 'g').toString()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That would work, but `/()/g` is simpler because there's no capturing going on here. (Which is what I posted in my answer)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Sure. But, I wasn't mentioning it to compete. Just noting it as a common definition in various engines for an "*empty*" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. (These methods are ranked from best practice to worst. I recommend the first one, and I *highly* discourage the last.)

---

Use `split`/`join`, which would be a better method with less overhead. No need for a regex here:

```
'foo'.split('').join(' ');
```

Or use the `RegExp` constructor

```
'foo'.replace(new RegExp('', 'g'), ' ');
```

Or, add a useless group (not recommended because it's unclear at first glance):

```
'foo'.replace(/()/g, ' ');
```

---

One more comment, based on your last paragraph:

> How can I achieve this using a regex literal, or is it not possible and I would have to create a Regex object?

They are literally the same thing:

[image: screenshot]

"using a regex literal... or... Regex object" doesn't make sense, because a regex literal *is* a `RegExp` object.

Comment: The regex might be faster in some browsers, here's a useless test http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-regex-literal-replace

Comment: The useless group approach will add a space before and after the string.See here: http://regex101.com/r/pT9mT5

Comment: @Alex It's never mentioned that's unwanted... in fact, that's what *would* happen if you could use `//` as a regex literal.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow OP states on the very first line (at the end): *for example `foo` becomes `f o o`*

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex instead:

```
/.(?!$)/g
```

You can read it as: "Find all char except the last one."

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Sample code

```
'foo'.replace(/.(?!$)/g, '$& ');
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/xH9bK1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `\B` (*everything but word boundary*)

```
'foo'.replace(/\B/g,' ');
```

or if you want to replace at every place

```
'foo'.replace(/\B|\b/g,' ');
```

Comment: this will change, for example, `foo bar` to `f o o b a r` (instead of the correct result, `f o o [space] b a r`). Also it's even more unclear and hard to understand. :P